# How to display a php string in a specified format

Tags: php, string

Consider the following string :

```
  $raw = "'Joy is the serious business of heaven.'.LEWIS,CLIVE STAPLES.1964-01-01.
|'We were not meant to be somebody--we were meant to know Somebody'.PIPER,JOHN STEPHEN.2011-07-17.|'He who sings prays twice.'.Hipponensis,Aurelius Augustinus.430-02-30.
|'The task of the modern educator is not to cut down jungles but to irrigate deserts.'.LEWIS,CLIVE STAPLES.1943-09-23.
|'There is not one blade of grass, there is no color in this world that is not intended to make us rejoice.'.Calvin,John C.1530-10-09.|
'The worth and excellency of a soul is to be measured by the object of its love.'.SCOUGAL,HENRY P.1678-08-23.
|'It is not the strength of your faith but the object of your faith that actually saves you.'.KELLER,TIMOTHY J.2013-01-14.
|'Truth is the agreement of our ideas with the ideas of God.'.Edwards,Jonathan Prtn.1703-09-23.
|'Each day we are becoming a creature of splendid glory or one of unthinkable horror.'.LEWIS,CLIVE STAPLES.1952-02-01.|'At your right hand are pleasures evermore..'.David,Jesse soun.1200-09-29.|'Tolerance is not about not having beliefs. It is about how your beliefs lead you to treat people who disagree with you.'.KELLER,TIMOTHY J.2015-10-23.
|'It is better to lose your life than to waste it.'.PIPER,JOHN STEPHEN.2000-05-33.|
'It is not opinions that man needs: it is TRUTH...'.Bonar Horatius B.1885-02-12.https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/133605.Horatius_Bonar|
'Nothing could be more irrational than the idea that something comes from nothing.'SPROUL,CHARLES ROBERT.2006-03-23.
|'He is no fool who gives what he cannot keep to gain that which he cannot lose.'.Elliot,James Phillip.1944-07-26.
";
```

It contains a quote,the author(surname,first_name second_name),date and the url_reference
 You are required to Display the following data as follows (NB: The author's  first_name can be clicked to open the url_reference on a new tab)

```
  (a). "Quote" - first_name second_name,surname (YEAR).
  (b). .......
  (c). .......
  (For example                                                                                                  *
    a) "The worth and excellency of a soul is to be measured by the object of its love." -  HENRY P,SCOUGAL (1678).                                      *
  )
Summary
 -- Total quotes : total.
 -- Total unique authors : total(list of author surnames - comma separated)
```

Comment: and your efforts so far are...?

Comment: We are not required to do anything. You are required to display the data in a format.

Comment: $token = strtok($raw, "|");

while ($token !== false) {
    echo("{$token}<br />");
    $token = strtok("|");
}

Answer (score -2):

For formatted output, use an integrated function `printf`

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) is the `printf` documentation.

> Edit: Suppose you have your data in the given form

```
$data = array("quote" => "It is better to lose your life than to waste it.", 
              "name" => "JOHN STEPHEN", "lastname" => "PIPER", 
              "date" => "2000-05-33", "url" => "URL link");
```

Let's now firstly implement a simple `print line` function:

```
function print_formatted_line($data) {
  printf("'%s' - <a href='%s' target='_blank'>%s</a>, %s (%s)<br>", 
    $data["quote"], $data["url"], $data["name"], $data["lastname"], date('Y', strtotime($$data["date"])));
}
```

Now you can print it simply as follows

`print_formatted_line($data); // passing an array to function`

Since your data is unreadable, and hence we are unable to perform and implement any logic, we need to transform it into something more readable. To obtain this, let's parse your `$raw` string. 
I have written a simple code for the specific example to extract the data from the given string.

```
 $raw = "'Joy is the serious business of heaven.'.LEWIS,CLIVE STAPLES.1964-01-01.
|'We were not meant to be somebody--we were meant to know Somebody'.PIPER,JOHN STEPHEN.2011-07-17.|'He who sings prays twice.'.Hipponensis,Aurelius Augustinus.430-02-30.
|'The task of the modern educator is not to cut down jungles but to irrigate deserts.'.LEWIS,CLIVE STAPLES.1943-09-23.
|'There is not one blade of grass, there is no color in this world that is not intended to make us rejoice.'.Calvin,John C.1530-10-09.|
'The worth and excellency of a soul is to be measured by the object of its love.'.SCOUGAL,HENRY P.1678-08-23.
|'It is not the strength of your faith but the object of your faith that actually saves you.'.KELLER,TIMOTHY J.2013-01-14.
|'Truth is the agreement of our ideas with the ideas of God.'.Edwards,Jonathan Prtn.1703-09-23.
|'Each day we are becoming a creature of splendid glory or one of unthinkable horror.'.LEWIS,CLIVE STAPLES.1952-02-01.|'At your right hand are pleasures evermore..'.David,Jesse soun.1200-09-29.|'Tolerance is not about not having beliefs. It is about how your beliefs lead you to treat people who disagree with you.'.KELLER,TIMOTHY J.2015-10-23.
|'It is better to lose your life than to waste it.'.PIPER,JOHN STEPHEN.2000-05-33.|
'It is not opinions that man needs: it is TRUTH...'.Bonar,Horatius B.1885-02-12.https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/133605.Horatius_Bonar|
'Nothing could be more irrational than the idea that something comes from nothing.'.SPROUL,CHARLES ROBERT.2006-03-23.
|'He is no fool who gives what he cannot keep to gain that which he cannot lose.'.Elliot,James Phillip.1944-07-26.
";

$iterData = explode('|', $raw, -1); // divide data by delim parametar "|"
$output = array(); // array to save the formatted data in

foreach($iterData as $key) {
  $quote_rest = explode("'.", $key, 2);  // divide one string into strings [0] => quote, [1] => other data
  $lastname_rest = explode(",",  $quote_rest[1], 2); // divide "[1] => other data" to array "[0] => lastname, [1] => name.date.url"
  $name_date_url = explode(".",  $lastname_rest[1], 3); // finally, extract data from [1] => name.date.url to 

  // create array of extracted data
  $data = array("quote" => substr($quote_rest[0], 1), 
                "name" => $name_date_url[0], 
                "lastname" => $lastname_rest[0], 
                "date" => $name_date_url[1], 
                "url" => $name_date_url[2]);
  // insert data to output array
  array_push($output, $data);

  // print data
  print_formatted_line($data); // pass data to output function
} 

/// implementation...
```

Note that now you have the data saved in the `output` array over which you can implement the rest of your program logic.